# load data in form_tag without refreshing page in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a rails project, I have 2 controller:tasks and product. I want get a product name in `views/tasks/_form.html.erb` in a `form_tag` and find the product's data from database and show the detail of product to user by javascript without reloading the page. I have below code:

tasks_controller:

```
  class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  layout "task"

  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json

  def show_product
    @product = Product.all
  end

  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /tasks/new
  def new
    @list_of_category = Category.all
    @list_of_product = Product.all
    @reporter = Reporter.find(params[:reporter_id])
    @task = Task.new
  end

  # GET /tasks/1/edit
  def edit
    @list_of_category = Category.all
    @list_of_product = Product.all
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    @task.responsibility = current_user.responsibility
    @task.reporter = @reporter
    @task.date_time = Time.now
    @task.trace_code = (Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tasks/1
  # DELETE /tasks/1.json
  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:responsibility_id, :reporter_id, :date_time, :trace_code, :status, :describe, :category_id, :product_id)
    end
end
```

views/tasks/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag 'tasks/show_product', :remote => true, :method => :get  do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q %><br/>
    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
<div id="response">

</div>
```

views/tasks/show_product.js.erb

```
$("#response").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'tasks/show_product') %>")
```

views/tasks/_show_product.html.erb

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

routes.rb

```
match "/tasks/show_product" => "tasks#show_product" , :via => :get
```

but when I click on `submit_tag`, product name don't send from `form_tag` and don't occur any change in page.

log of system when I click on `submit_tag`:

```
    Started GET "/tasks/show_product?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Product+1&commit=Save+changes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-04 13:35:36 +0430
Processing by TasksController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>"Product 1", "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"show_product"}
  Task Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "show_product"]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Task with id=show_product):
  app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:85:in `set_task'


  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (29.0ms)
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: can you post piece of log after click submit_tag

Comment: from log i see problem in form try use `show_product` instead `tasks/show_product`.

Comment: this you query `"q"=>"Product 1"` and nothing found by query `404 Not Found`

Comment: log should have info about render. have anything? like  `Rendered views/tasks/show_product.js.erb (12ms)`

Comment: you form route to wrong action `TasksController#show` but need to `TasksController#show_product` please post full `TasksController` to you question.

Comment: try `form_tag '', :remote => true, :method => :get` this in form.

Comment: I use this, but by this code, the `show_product` action is not running. If this action is not running, the .js.erb is don't running too.

Comment: try rename `show_product` to something `all_product` or else without word `show` at begin. and pass name action in `form_tag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Task with id=show_product)
```

The problem is basically that you're trying to load the `show` action. Typical cause is tha you've declared the path *after* you've declared `resources :tasks` in your `routes.rb` file

Try this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :tasks do
    collection do
        get :show_products
    end
end

#app/views/tasks/_form.html.erb
<%= form_tag tasks_show_products_path, :remote => true, :method => :get  do %>
```

This will give you a [`collection` route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#%22adding-collection-routes), which you can then call using the corresponding path helper. This should work as your current error is caused by a conflict with the `show` action

Comment: Your answer is ok when I use `'show_products'` instead of `tasks_show_products_path` in form_tag. When I use `tasks_show_products_path` I get below error: `NameError in Tasks#new`,`undefined local variable or method `tasks_show_products_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000058e5a58>:0x00000004ecc238>`. Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure my recommendation for the path helper name is a correct one? Thanks for upvote btw